# git diff between two branches not matching the changes during a merge

Tags: git, git-merge

I have two branches, master and feature.
If I do:

```
git diff --name-only master..feature
```

I get a long list of files, some of them source code, so not excluded by .gitignore

But, when I try to merge feature into master:

```
git checkout master
git merge feature
```

I get only a single file changed in master during the merge process.

Why does this happen?

Another interesting thing is, if I try the reverse and merge master into feature, files that were created in the feature branch are deleted.

How do I fix this and avoid this issue in the future?

Comment: Try `git diff master...feature` ([triple dots](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+triple+dots)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not a bug.

Consider the following simple example.  Suppose there is a file named `example.txt`.  In branch X, it reads:

```
This is
quite
a file.
```

In branch Y, it reads:

```
This is
not
a file.
```

What should the result of merging branches X and Y be?  Specifically, what *content* do you expect to appear in the file named `example.txt`?

What information, if any, have I failed to give you?  What else do you need to know before you can even *answer* this question?

(Try to come up with an answer before you read on.)

#### Git is about commits, not files

Before we go on, let's note that the unit of storage you deal with, in Git, is the *commit*, not the file.  It's true that commits *contain* files, but the general idea here is that it's a package deal: a commit has a *full snapshot* of *all* of the files.  If we take some starting commit:

```
git checkout somebranch
```

and split a big file, `bigfile.py`, into two smaller files, `small1.py` and `small2.py` and *remove* `bigfile.py` entirely and then commit, the new commit **lacks** `bigfile.py` *and* **adds** the two smaller files, as compared with the old commit.  When we check out the old commit, we have just one of the three files—the big one—and when we check out the new commit, we have just two of the three files.  It's a package deal: you can pick the commit with one file, or the commit with two, but you never get both the big file and *one* of the small ones, or all three files, or some other combination.

Still, commits *contain* files, and that will be important later when we get around to merging.  But besides containing files—that's their main data: a snapshot of *every* file (as of the way it appeared when you made that commit)—each commit contains some *metadata*, or information about the commit.  This includes the stuff you see in `git log` output: the name and email address of the person who made the commit, and a date-and-time-stamp, for instance.<sup>1</sup>

In amongst all this metadata, Git stores, in each commit, the raw *hash ID* of some earlier commit(s).  Most commits store exactly one earlier commit hash ID.  These hash IDs are the "true names" of the commits, too: they're how Git actually *finds* each commit.  The commits are stored in a big [key-value database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database), with the hash ID of the commit being the key, and the commit's content being the value.

With each commit storing the *previous* commit's hash ID, we end up with a nice simple linear chain of commits.  If we use uppercase letters to stand in for each hash ID, we get drawings that look like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where `H` is the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.  Inside commit `H`, Git has stored the actual hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  Inside commit `G`, Git stored the hash ID of still-earlier commit `F`, and so on.

These chains allow Git to work backwards, from the *latest* commits back to earlier ones.  These *are* the history in a Git repository, so these chains are crucial to using Git.  And, since each commit stores a *full snapshot*, we have to have Git *compare* two commits to see what changed.  If we have Git compare the snapshot in `G` to the snapshot in `H`, for instance, that tells us what we changed when we *made* `H` *from* `G`.

So, this is what `git log` does: it starts at the latest commit (such as `H`), prints out the hash ID and the metadata, and if we used `-p` to get patches, extracts both `G` and `H` (to a temporary memory area) and compares the two commit's snapshots to figure out what changed, and show us that.  Then, having shown commit `H`, Git moves backwards one step to commit `G`: it prints out the hash ID and metadata, and if we used `-p`, compares `F`-vs-`G`.  Having printed out `G`, `git log` moves back one more step to `F`, and so on down the line.

(In other words, Git works *backwards*.  I won't emphasize this more here but it explains a lot about Git, once you realize this.)

---

<sup>1</sup>If you use `git log --pretty=fuller`, you'll see that each commit actually has two of these: an *author* and a *committer*.  Each one is made up of a triplet: name, email, timestamp.  Usually both are the same these days, except for cherry-picked commits, where the author of the original commit is retained, and the committer is the person who did the cherry-pick, with the committer time stamp being the time of the cherry-pick action.

---

#### Branch names merely help us *find* commits

To make the above work, we have to know—somehow—the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.  We need to give that hash ID to Git, because Git can only *find* commits by their hash IDs, in the end.  We could write down these hash IDs, jotting them on paper, or on a whiteboard, or something.  But they're really big and ugly and hard to type in correctly.  Plus, we have a *computer*.  Why not have the *computer* remember the hash IDs for us?  We could add a second database to our Git repository: it would hold *names*, like `master` or `develop` or `feature`, and with those names, remember the hash ID of the *last* (most recent, most useful, whatever) commit.

That's just what a branch name is: it's an entry in a names database.  The actual name is extended a bit: `master` is really `refs/heads/master` and `feature` is really `refs/heads/feature`.  This leaves room for other kinds of names, like tag names: `v2.1` is really `refs/tags/v2.1`.  But for branch names in particular, they all hold *commit hash IDs*—one each—and that hash ID is the ID of the *last* commit that we're going to consider to be "on the branch".

If we only have one branch, everything is easy:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

Here, the branch name `master` is the only name, and it holds the hash ID of our most recent commit, commit `H`.  So the *name* `master` *points to* the commit at the end of the chain.  That lets us (and Git) access commit `H`.  Commit `H` points backwards to commit `G`, which lets us (and Git) access it; commit `G` points backwards again, and so on.

If we create a *new* branch name now, such as `feature`, we can pick any of the existing commits to have this new name point-to.  Most often, though, we'll pick the commit we're using: `H`, via `master`.  So we'll get:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- feature, master
```

Now we have a problem.  Which *branch name* are we using?  To remember, we'll add a special name, `HEAD`, and attach it to one of these two branch names.  Let's attach `HEAD` to `feature`—by running `git checkout feature` if necessary—and draw that:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- feature (HEAD), master
```

We're still using commit `H`, but now we're using it because of the name `feature`.

Now let's create a new commit, in the usual way: modify some files, maybe even create new ones and/or remove existing ones, and use `git add` and/or `git rm` as needed to get them all updated, and `git commit` the result.  Without worrying too much about all the details, this has Git save away a new snapshot, add some metadata, and write out the collection as a new commit.  The new commit gets a new, unique hash ID—something random-looking, and unpredictable since it depends on the *exact time* at which we make the commit—but we'll just call it commit `I`.  The new commit will point backwards to the existing commit `H`:

```
             I
            /
...--F--G--H
```

Once the new commit *exists*, even before we get back to being able to run more commands, Git now does its last special trick: it writes the new commit's hash ID into the *current branch name*, i.e., the one `HEAD` is attached-to.  Since that's `feature`, we get:

```
             I   <-- feature (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

Commit `H` comes right before commit `I`, but it's still the *last* commit on the `master` branch.  Commit `I` is the *last* commit on `feature`, but commits up through `H` are on `feature` too.

Let's go ahead and make one more commit on `feature` now:

```
             I--J   <-- feature (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

and then run `git checkout master`.  This will take our `HEAD` away from `feature` and attach it to `master` instead.  It will also update our work area so that we are using the contents of commit `H`, rather than the contents of commit `J`: all our files now match `H`, not `J`.  Any updates we made and snapshotted into `I` and `J` are safely stored there, in `I` and `J`, but they're gone from our *view* now, as we have commit `H` out:

```
             I--J   <-- feature
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

We could now make another new branch name, say, `feature2`, and attach `HEAD` to that:

```
             I--J   <-- feature
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- feature2 (HEAD), master
```

and then make two new commits on `feature2`:

```
             I--J   <-- feature
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             K--L   <-- feature2 (HEAD)
```

Or, we could just go ahead and make these commits directly on `master`:

```
             I--J   <-- feature
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- master (HEAD)
```

As far as the *graph itself* goes—the set of commits with the backwards-pointing arrows between them (drawn here as lines because the arrow graphics available in text are poor)—it doesn't matter: we can't *change* any *existing* commits (ever), but we can always add new commits, and either way, we end up with this set of commits.  It's just a question of which *names* **find** these commits.  But Git allows us to create, destroy, or move *branch names* any time we like.  The commits don't change; it's just that the *names* we use to *find* them might be different.

#### Merging

It's time to answer the question above: what's missing?

When we *merge* some commits in Git, this is all about *combining work*.  The idea is that someone, in some series of commits (`I-J` perhaps), did some work, and someone—probably someone else—in some other series of commits (`K-L`) did some work.  That gives us this:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

Because of the nature of commits—they never change—we can tell, from this graph, that these two lines of work *started* from a *common starting point*, namely commit `H`.  It's really easy to see, visually, that everything in `J` is descended from `H`, and the same is true for `L`.  They also descended from `G`, but `H` is "better" because it's "closer" to the end-point commits.

Now, we already know that Git can compare two snapshots like `G` and `H`, or `I` and `J`.  What if Git can easily compare `H` directly with `J`?  Well, it *can;* and if we have Git do that, we'll find out what's *different* from `H` to `J`.  That's the *work someone did* on the top line.  So those are the *changes* in `br1`.

Similarly, if we have Git compare what's in `H` to what's in `L`, we will find out what work someone did on the bottom line.  Whatever files are different, and whatever rules we use to *change* the contents of files in `H` to those in `L`, that's what someone did on `br2`.

This also tells us what's missing.  In order to merge `example.txt`, we need not just the two *end-point* files—one says `quite` on line 2, for instance, and the other says `not` on line 2—but also the *base copy* of the file.  The base copy of `example.txt` is the copy of the file in commit `H`.  Commit `H` is the **merge base** of the two tip commits, and its copy of each file is how we figure out what *changed*.

If the base copy says:

```
This is
quite
a file.
```

then we know *nothing* changed in the one that still says `quite`, and one line changed in the one that says `not`.

If the base copy says:

```
This is
not
a file.
```

then we know *nothing* changed in the one that still says `not`, and one line changed in the one that says `quite`.

If the base copy has no line 2—if it reads, in its entirety:

```
This is
a file.
```

then we have a *merge conflict*, because both people made a change: both added a line-2, but they added *different* line-2-s.

#### What this means for your case

If the two branch tip commits—the one found by the name `master`, and the one found by the name `feature`—are different, that just tells us that they're different.  The recipe that Git comes up with, that will change one commit to make it match another commit, just tells us how to change the one tip commit into the other tip commit.

If the *merge base* commit between these two branch-tip commits is some *third* commit,<sup>2</sup> we need to know what's in that third commit, because *that's* how `git merge` will figure out what changed in `master` and what changed in `feature`.  The merge command will then attempt to *combine* those *two sets of changes*, applying the combined changes to whatever is in the merge base.

As [phd commented](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd), you can use the triple-dot notation with the `git diff` command:

```
git diff master...feature
```

for instance.  This has Git:

- find the merge base between the two tip commits (let's call that `$B`); then
- run the equivalent of `git diff $B feature`

which tells you what changed on `feature`, with respect to this merge base.  If you then run the same command with the two names swapped around:

```
git diff feature...master
```

Git will find the merge base of the same two tip commits,<sup>3</sup> and then diff `$B` vs `master`: this shows you what changed on `master`.

Again, what `git merge` does for these cases is:<sup>4</sup>

- run *both* diffs, saving the output in a temporary area;
- get the *merge base* version of every file;
- combine the diffs, if possible; and
- apply the *combined* diffs to the merge base versions of the files.

If this all goes well, `git merge` will make a *merge commit* from the result.  A merge commit isn't very different from a regular non-merge commit: it still has a snapshot of all files—as built by the combining process above—and some metadata.  The special thing about a merge commit is that it lists *both* branch-tip commits as its parents, so that Git can go back along *both branches* (which are now combined into one "branch" via the merge commit: this exposes a flaw in the word "branch"; see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)).

---

<sup>2</sup>There *are* some degenerate cases here.  In particular, if the merge base is one of the two branch tip commits, we either have a simple "fast-forward-able" case, or else there's nothing to merge.  Given what you've posted, you must not have one of these cases, though.

<sup>3</sup>If there's only one merge base commit—and this is normally the case—it doesn't matter what order the two branch tip commits are listed in.  For some complex commit graphs, however, there may be two or more merge base commits.  Here, the picture gets rather murky.  The `git diff` command didn't handle this very well, until quite recently; `git merge` handles it better, but it's still tricky.

<sup>4</sup>This description makes a lot of assumptions about how you're doing the merge, the shape of the graph, and so on, and is otherwise greatly simplified vs what `git merge` really does internally.  The idea is to capture the overall goal, without getting into some of the stickier mechanics.  For instance, this disregards how merge handles the case of a *renamed* file.

Comment: Wow, this explanation is worthy of a whole blog post!! Thanks so much for taking the time to write it out, it helped solve my issue and also gave me a much better understanding of git!